# Stream file from Minio to web browser

Tags: go, amazon-s3, minio

I have a backend web site written in golang using Gin Web Framework and a Minio Serevr with some file stored. What I'm trying to achive is that from my web page (written in ReactJS) I can download a file that is stored in minio. So far I'm able to connect to minio and retrive a file with these line of code:

```
minioClient, err := minio.New(endpoint, accessKeyID, secretAccessKey, useSSL)
object, err := minioClient.GetObject(dataConnection.BucketName, fileName, minio.GetObjectOptions{})
```

The object I get in return implements Reader, ReaderAt, Seeker, Closer for a HTTP stream. Indeed I would like to stream it directly to the web browser instead of saving it locally and then serve it again to the web browser. But from here Im a bit lost

SOLVED:

```
file, err := minioClient.GetObject(dataConnection.BucketName, path+file, minio.GetObjectOptions{})
extraHeaders := map[string]string{
            "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=" + fileRequest.FileName,
        }
c.DataFromReader(http.StatusOK, size, "application/octet-stream", file, extraHeaders)
```

Comment: Use [DataFromReader](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin?tab=doc#Context.DataFromReader) to copy the object directly to the response.

Comment: Why that complicated? You can make the according file accessible via http by making it public. Further reading: https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-client-complete-guide.html#policy

Comment: Hey @NiBE did you manage to get what you were searching for??

Comment: Hi @BharathKuppala I update the question, thanks!